# Несколько кареток в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите, есть ли возможность в Идее по очереди выделить несколько слов из разных мест, аналогично `Ctrl+ЛКМ` в Sublime Text?

Comment: Для чего такое может потребоваться?

Comment: @Эникейщик вытянуть пару человеконазваний полей модели из модели, удалить несколько идущих не подряд строк, заменить одно название другим в одних местах, не трогая другие. Очень полезная и удобная функция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно выделять разные слова создавая новый курсор, например под Windows комбинация <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click добавляет курсор, а та же комбинация, но с двойным кликом, добавляет курсор выделяя слово.

Comment: Странно, у меня под линуксом почему-то это не работало, из-за этого вопрос и задал. Пришлось менять хоткеи на это, тогда заработало.